Execute something after payable is done with the payment
I'm a beginner trying to make a basic fundraising project. There are going to be several projects to which the users can send funds, and there's a cap amount to each project. Now, I want to emit an event whenever the cap amount for a project is funded.
Is there a way to execute some logic after the payable has accepted and received a payment?
My code so far is like:
function fundProject(uint _projectId) external payable {
    uint remainingFundNeeded = projects[_projectId].amountNeeded - projects[_projectId].amountFunded;
    if (msg.value > remainingFundNeeded){
        uint change = msg.value - remainingFundNeeded;
        // Return the change.
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(change);
    }

    // After the function has accepted the payment I want to emit this event.
    if (msg.value >= remainingFundNeeded) {
        emit ProjectFundCompleted(_projectId);

        payable(projects[_projectId].recipient)
            .transfer(projects[_projectId].amountNeeded);
    }
}

